# Map list of children to parent object from join table with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've searched and can't find a similar question where three tables come into play. I have three tables: Parent, Child, and ParentChild. ParentChild is a many-to-many join table that lets you set multiple children to multiple parents. I'm using .Net Core 5.

Here are the dto classes for the tables:

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentChild {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my linq statement:

```
var parentChildGroup = from parent in parentList 
                    join parentChild in parentChildList 
                    on parent.Id equals parentChild.ParentId
                    join child in childList on parentChild.ChildId equals child.Id
                    group child by child.Id into newGroup 
                    select new { 
                        Children = newGroup, 
                    };
```

I've gone through several different iterations based on examples I've found online and I've created a .Net fiddle with the full code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hh12V3

What I want is a list of all Parent objects with a child list of all Child objects.

So, I should be able to iterate through Parent.Children for example. I just can't figure out how to insert the group of Child objects into the Children property of the Parent. It's probably simple and I've made this overly complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Pls post what  net version you use. And what pourpose  ParentChild table. I can't see why you need it. You don't need it to set multiple children to a single parent.

Comment: .Net Core 5. The whole system is already in production with 100s of installs, so modifying the database isn't possible. I didn't design this part of the table. There are other columns in the ParentChild table as well, such as SequenceNumber that allows us to order the children within the parent. Children can also be ordered differently depending on which Parent they belong to, so the join table is necessary here.

Comment: If the same children can have several parents that it is many-to-many relations. Do you have this case?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I edited the original question to many-to-many. My fault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the model of the parent to contains list of children

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Children {get;set;} // <<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

then you can select it as following

```
var parentChildGroup =parentList.Select(p=>
{
    p.Children = parentChildList.Where(pc=>pc.ParentId == p.Id)
                                .SelectMany(pc=>childList.Where(c=>c.Id == pc.ChildId))
                                .ToList();
    return p;
});
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change was make the parentList an actual list using ToList(). Otherwise I would get this error: "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree”. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you use net5 this should be enough

```
var parentChildGroup = db.Parents.Include(c=> c.Children).ToList();
```